Get data about rendered entities (mapnik) for each zoom
I'm using mapnik (mod_tile + renderd) to generate tiles based on data from PostGIS. The data is very simple, several countries with roads, names, etc. There is a style description file (xml), where the style is specified (classic OSM).
Can I somehow get data about the rendered entities for each zoom?
For example, on distant zooms only the names of large cities and countries are displayed, so I need to get this data (excluding those not rendered for these zooms).
